# assign public domain on linux

Tags: linux, domain-name

I have all my domains parked with Godaddy registrar, and now I have aquired a small dedicated server to migrate all my sites.

How do I park my domains in the new site? 
The server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Box with Apache and Nginx running.
The only way to access the server right now it's via IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Setup your own DNS (typically bind) server, change the DNS delegation to point to your  own server and then create DNS records for your server. That way you have full control over the system.
2. Ask somebody else to run the DNS for you and create records for your server. If your server doesn't have a fixed IP this is a much better solution. There is a number of good dns providers around, such as dyndns. They will typically take a small yearly fee to handle your domains.

GoDaddy are large, but I would personally avoid them. I have bad experience with them.

Comment: We have a few domains where GoDaddy provides DNS for, and we've not had any problems with them at all in the 1.5 to 2 years we've been using them. As spammy as their site is, their technicians seem to know what they are doing and are fast and helpful. I'm not saying that pehrs is wrong, just that your mileage may vary. If you're already using GoDaddy for your domain registration, they do provide DNS services for free. I would definitely recommend #2 over #1 unless you know what you're doing.